# Add a title to a DNA bin plot in R

Tags: r, image, plot, ape

The R package `ape` allows us to create a plot of a `DNAbin` class object which contains information on DNA sequence alignments.

Suppose I have a DNAbin object called `myDNAbin`. I can use

```
> image.DNAbin(myDNAbin)
```

to generate a plot of the sequence alignments. Can I add a customized title to this plot?

The usual parameters such as

```
> image.DNAbin(myDNAbin, main = "my title)
```

don't appear to work.

Comment: You could try adding it post-hoc with `title()`, e.g., `image.DNAbin(myDNAbin); title(main = "my title")`

Comment: Thanks! This works with some minor adjustments, e.g. `title(main = "my title", line =+3)`